# Python - how to remove a specific first word from list of long strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list as shown below. I want to remove the first word which will always be 'Value' from my list of strings. I am able to do this by indexing (code below) but is there any way to do this by identifying the actual phrase 'Value'?

Example list

```
my_lst=['Value today is great weather.','Value final dataset.','Value for money.']

new_lst=[]
for i in my_lst:
    new_lst.append(i[6:])
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current way? Why do you want something else?

Comment: I wanted to access the word directly to ensure exceptions were handled - rather than indexing

Comment: What exceptions, and handled how?

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove a prefix, so...

```
>>> 'Value foo bar'.removeprefix('Value ')
'foo bar'
```

Comment: This method is available only in 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

A generic way to remove prefix words could be done as:

```
target_word = "Value"
if mystring.startswith(target_word):
    mystring = mystring[len(target_word):]
```

You can loop this and rename your variables as required.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
my_lst=['Value today is great weather.','Value final dataset.','Value for money.']

new_lst=[]
for i in my_lst:
    if i[0:5]=="Value":
        new_lst.append(i[6:])
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: Your end index of your slice is incorrect.  You need `[0:6]`.  or `[:len("Value")]`.  Of course, I prefer `startswith`

Comment: It works fine it check is the first 5 index equal to value and then if it is it starts at the next index which is 6 to the end of the string hench [6:]

Comment: [0:5] checks the first 5 indexs for the string Value

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I'm wrong.  I can't edit my comment, but I don't believe in deleting my shame. So there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expression substitution:

```
new_lst = [re.sub('^Value\s+', '', w) for w in my_lst]
#['today is great weather.', 'final dataset.', 'for money.']
```

Explanation: `"^Value\s+"` is the word `"Value"` at the beginning of a string (`"^"`), followed by one or more (`"+"`) spaces (`"\s"`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *list comprehension* with [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) as:

```
my_lst = ['Value today is great weather.', 'Value final dataset.', 'Value for money.']
my_word = 'Value'

new_list = [s[len(my_word):] for s in my_lst if s.startswith(my_word)]
# where `new_list` will give you list as:
#    [' today is great weather.', ' final dataset.', ' for money.']
```

If you are on **Python 3.9+**, you can use [`str.removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) (skipping [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) check) as:

```
my_lst = ['Value today is great weather.', 'Value final dataset.', 'Value for money.']
my_word = 'Value'

new_list = [s.removeprefix(my_word) for s in my_lst]
# [' today is great weather.', ' final dataset.', ' for money.']
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this one:

```
new_list = [word.split('Value ')[-1] for word in mylst]
```

Comment: what if there are more than one "Value" word are present in the string?

Comment: agree, it doesn't rescue about having more than one 'Value ' str in item string. But if you know well your requirements it can fit perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You may use :

```
new_lst = " ".join(my_lst.split()[1:])
```

It will remove the first world of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression sub and look for Value at the start of the sentence

```
my_list=['Value today is great weather.','Value final dataset.','Value for money.']

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i]=re.sub('^Value ','',my_list[i])

print(my_list)
```

output:

```
['today is great weather.', 'final dataset.', 'for money.']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can [`removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) like this (only for Python >3.9):

```py
>>> my_lst = ['Value today is great weather.', 'Value final dataset.', 'Value for money.']
>>> phrase = 'Value '
>>> [x.removeprefix(phrase) for x in my_lst]
['today is great weather.', 'final dataset.', 'for money.']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

my_lst.replace("value" , "")

"Replace" is used to replace one specific word with another word.